# How to customize MacBooks' keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I spilled a juice on my MacBook-Pro keyboard. Consequently, some keys like `2, esc and tab` don't work anymore on my keyboard.

Is there anyway to change those disabled keys with combination of some other keys, like Fn,Ctrl, Option+ something, using an app or a command?

Comment: The amount of time and effort you are going to spend finding, paying for, configuring and training yourself to use that solution that's completely un-natural, is peanuts compared what it costs to get a [replacement keyboard](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=macbook+pro+keyboard)

Comment: This is not what I asked! @Allan

Comment: @Electricman I have done this before for a friend here you go http://superuser.com/questions/665494/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-os-x  Esc can be changed natively on new OSX sierra I have heard.

Comment: @Allan this question could be worse.  I have actually done this before for a friend.

Comment: @Allan that is without installation costs though.  Realistic you might be able to get a 3rd party to do it for $100 but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is really like taking the car to a mechanic, asking them to fix the horn because the brakes have failed. Just get it fixed.

Comment: I think it is like having an open jeep with no seatbelts.  You only want to drive it it good weather and with clear high ways and minimal traffic but it is drivable.  Depending on the keys broken your laptop can still work pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since this is on the stackexchange network I am going to just link to it here.

Basically [this is how you change the native keys](https://superuser.com/questions/665494/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-in-os-x).

To change the esc key [you need this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-in-mac-os-x/8437594#84375940).

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost solved it with Ukelele method. @william

Comment: @Electricman can I help anymore or did you figure it out?

Comment: The problem with some keys have been solved. But something odd is going on. Some combination keys like ctrl+c or v are not working anymore in this keyboard layout, obtained by ukelele. But it might be for some other reasons. I need time to figure it out and ask a question. Thank you so much for your help @william

Comment: @Electricman I think you meant to say command+c or v but yes that is possible.

Comment: yes with command. @william